# Hadoop Streaming job error

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

Hello I am trying to run Hadoop Streaming job using Python in EMR 4.7.2 with command as follows:

```
hadoop-streaming -archives s3://mybucket/scripts/HDP/python_scripts/py.tgz -mapper py.tgz/processRAWData.py -input /data/raw_combined/ -output s3://ccv-eu01-private/temp/logoptemp/ -jobconf mapred.task.timeout=14000000 -jobconf mapred.tasktracker.expiry.interval=14000000 -jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -jobconf mapred.map.tasks=15000
```

This job use to run smoothly for 3 months but now it is failing & following are the logs :

```
caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1486363893937_0003/container_1486363893937_0003_01_000055/./py.tgz/processRAWData_unix.py": error=26, Text file busy
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:219)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=26, Text file busy
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more
```

I checked for solving the above error but I couldn't got any root cause of the error..Why is this error occurring ? Can anyone help me with a solution to overcome this error ? Thank You